# To hide a div on Page Load using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, redcap

I have some div in my code as mentioned below. Through Jquery I want to hide div having class="redCategory redCap vertical".  My Jquery code to hide 
div is  `$(".redCap").hide();` but after page load div is not getting hidden. What should be Jquery? I want to hide div during page load.

```
<div class="redLinkContainer">

    <span class="accessibleText" aria-level="1" role="heading"></span>
    <div class="redCategory redHome adjacent"><a> href="https://example.com/">1</a></div>
    <div class="redCategory redContact adjacent"><a> href="https://example.com/">2</a>></div>
    <div class="redCategory Things adjacent"><a> href="https://example.com/">3</a></div>
    <div class="redCategory redCap vertical">
        <a class="red CategoryTitle redCategoryHeader" href="https://example.com/">4</a>
          </div>
     <div class="redCategory ManyThings adjacent"><a> href="https://example.com/">5</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your full js code?

Comment: I think it depends where you put your JavaScript code. Before HTML? It'll trigger too early.

Comment: Are you hiding the div after the page is loaded , i.e inside $(document).ready(function(){
$(".redCap").hide();
}); 

Or without using document ready function ?

If you don't use document ready it will not work . Also is there any JS which unhides all div ? This might conflict with hide  . 

Share your code will help more to identify ?

Answer (score 0):

put hidden in the div:

```html
<div class="redCategory redCap vertical" hidden>
        <a class="red CategoryTitle redCategoryHeader" href="https://example.com/">4</a>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css file

```
.divHide{display:none;}
.divShow{display:block;}
```

Your HTML code:

```
<div class="redLinkContainer divHide"></div>
```

when the page load div is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tag is wrong format. Please use proper format

```
<a class="red CategoryTitle redCategoryHeader" href="https://example.com/">4</a>
```

Please find the Below URL,(check your code)

https://jsfiddle.net/wg62c8j5/

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests here and it work as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".redCap").hide();

</script>

<div class="redLinkContainer">

    <span class="accessibleText" aria-level="1" role="heading"></span>
    <div class="redCategory redHome adjacent"><a>   href="https://example.com/">1</a></div>
    <div class="redCategory redContact adjacent"><a> href="https://example.com/">2</a></div>
    <div class="redCategory Things adjacent"><a> href="https://example.com/">3</a></div>
    <div class="redCategory redCap vertical">
       <a class="red CategoryTitle redCategoryHeader" href="https://example.com/">4</a>
      </div>
  <div class="redCategory ManyThings adjacent"><a> href="https://example.com/">5</a></div>
```

Are you sure your JQuery library is being loaded ?